# Is there any problem with pandas merge currently?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using outer join to merge two tables. Let's say

`df1 = ['productID', 'Name']`

`df2 = ['userID', 'productID', 'usage']`

I tried to use outer join with merge function in pandas.

pd.merge(df1, df2[['userID','productID', 'usage']], on='productID', how = 'outer')

However, the error message I got is 
`'productID' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`

I googled this error message and saw a open [issue]: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/891

Any solution to my problem?

Comment: `'productID' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous` means your index is `productID` and a column , may be you have `set_index()` as product ID on either dataframes, either rename the index name or drop the same column and use `left_index`/`right_index` params of merge

Comment: Thanks @anky_91. The answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error means there is same index name like column `productID`:

```
#check it
print (df2.index.name)
```

Solution is remove/rename index name, e.g. by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.rename_axis(None)[['userID','productID', 'usage']], 
          on='productID', how = 'outer')
```